# I am confused relating Entropy in statistics with thermodynamics

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, entropy

The thing is in thermodynamics we learn entropy as a measure of energy of a system per unit temperature that isn't available for the system to do work. Again, statistically, entropy is a measure of number of ways in which a system can be arranged. I am confused why these two seemingly different concepts are identical(or atleast proportional) to each other.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How is $\frac{dQ}{T}$ measure of randomness of system?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/33372/how-is-fracdqt-measure-of-randomness-of-system)

Comment: [This](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/21955/ignorance-in-statistical-mechanics) could be of interest, too.

Comment: The textbook by Bergersen and Plischke spends some time relating the two.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to derive Shannon Entropy from Clausius Theorem?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/709644/how-to-derive-shannon-entropy-from-clausius-theorem) also this: https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/710156/247642

Comment: Also [1](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/11646/how-is-thermodynamic-entropy-defined-what-is-its-relationship-to-information-en), [2](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/598446/if-information-theoretic-and-thermodynamic-entropy-need-not-always-be-identical), [3](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/263197/is-information-entropy-the-same-as-thermodynamic-entropy), [4](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/629888/what-is-the-relation-between-thermodynamic-entropy-and-the-information-in-the-br), [5](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/408502/).