# Is there a thermodynamic process where entropy is constant but internal energy is not?

Tags: thermodynamics, energy, statistical-mechanics, energy-conservation, entropy

My professor asked me this and I haven't been able to find an answer. I know that entropy is constant in reversible processes like an adiabatic one, but in that case, the internal energy is also conserved.

Any ideas?

Comment: All adiabatic reversible processes have zero change in entropy, but their internal energy changes if work is done.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For an adiabatic and reversible transformation (for example the adiabatic compression of a gas), the entropy of the system does not change while it receives work: its internal energy changes.

Answer (score 5):

> I know that entropy is constant in reversible processes like an adiabatic one, but in that case, the internal energy is also conserved.

You sure about that?

What about a system doing reversible work?

Answer (score 4):

[The fundamental thermodynamic identity is](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_thermodynamic_relation)
$$
dU=TdS - pdV,
$$
which can be also written in terms of enthalpy as
$$
dH=TdS+Vdp.
$$
These relations readily suggest that we can change the internal energy by changing volume and/or pressure without changing entropy ($dS=0$), although in order to keep entropy constant these might have to be changed in a specific way.

More generally, **reversible thermodynamic processes** are the processes that do not result in total entropy change of the system with its environment (since otherwise, they would not be reversible - if entropy increased, reversibility would require decreasing it to return to the initial state.)

In this context it is worth mentioning that Gibbs' definition of entropy (*"Gibbs I"*) was explicitly designed in such a way as to reflect the *arrow of time*, i.e., irreversible direction of evolution of thermodynamic systems. While there exist alternative definitions of entropy, they can be shown to be equivalent to this definition in thermodynamic context (see [Is information entropy the same as thermodynamic entropy?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/739917/247642))